# Write update query in php to update set of rows - Zend framework

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I use the following code:

```
$str= array('createdid' => $creator_newid);  
$where = array();
$where['id IN']  = $instance_ids;
$this->_table->update($str, $where);
```

And here the `$instance_ids` contains set of string (that is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6…) and I'm getting zend error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: As you mentioned, $instance_ids is a set of string, this might be the problem. Please check with an array.

Comment: yeah, got some alternative way, sending them in quotes ('1','2','3',...) and also changed the update statement.. thank you @Prava-MindfireSolutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Zend_Db_Abstract methods like

public function updatestatus($updateAry,$id) {

```
            if(!empty($id)) {
                try{
                        $res = $this->getDbTable()->update($updateAry, array('user_id=?'=>$id));
                        if (false === $res) {
                            return 0;  // bool false returned, query failed
                        } else {
                            return 1;
                        }
                } catch (Zend_Exception $zex){}
            }
    }
```

here

$updateAry is the data you want to update.

array('user_id=?'=>$id) It is like were clause

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Zend_Db_Adapter` methods

```
$str = array('createdid' => $creator_newid);  
$where = array(
    $this->_table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id IN(?)', $instance_ids))
);
$this->_table->update($str, $where);
```

The adapter will carefully escape and quote params for you.